# Jquery BlockUI causes viewport to move around

Tags: jquery, blockui, jquery-blockui

I have a several screens long `div` which has buttons on top and bottom of it. Whenever those buttons are clicked the UI is blocked; this causes viewport position to jump to the middle of the `div`.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening and show `'Loading...'` message in the middle of the screen without viewport jumping around?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.